# Do tooth infections pockets build pressure?

Tags: infection, pressure

Here is a strange situation that happened these days. I had an infection in a tooth that had a root canal and a post with a crown. The infection was there for a while and these days, the whole thing (post, buildup and crown) got loose. The dentist said that it is an unusual situation and that usually the crown is the one that pops up. I’ve got a new crown, but I would like to understand what could have happened.

Is it possible that the infection pocket has built pressure and pushed the post out? It would make sense in a thermodynamic system, but is it the same in a human body? Is it possible (and I know this will sound weird) that that puss or whatever is in there vaporizes over time and adds some small vapor pockets?